# storing array of arrays in Redis

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, redis, memcached

I have a huge database with complex relations and want to cache some index and strings in order to have much faster access to them, so that I want to store them in some sort of cache to minimize accessing DB to fetch informations.

I searched and found Memcached and Redis can be a suitable for my purpose. After more researching, I found out Memcache has limitation about storing in it's "Value" ( Key -> Value ).

In Redis, Is it possible to store a multi dimension array ( array of arrays of arrays ) in a "Value" ( Key -> value ). which can be a 20MB or 30MB of data in maximum.

if Yes, Doesn't that decrease performance?

Comment: Both increase performance as they're ram based systems. just use memcached to cache all your sql queries so that rather than hitting the db users hit the memcache instead saves all around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Redis string values have a limit of 512MB.

**http://redis.io/topics/data-types**

String

> A String value can be at max 512 Megabytes in length.

List

> The max length of a list is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 elements (4294967295, more than 4 billion of elements per list).

Set

> The max number of members in a set is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (4294967295, more than 4 billion of members per set).

Hash

> Every hash can store up to 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 field-value pairs (more than 4 billion).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using mongoDB for your use case. It will enable indexing and querying complex nested structure and will be fast as well.